# Хтмл отладчик

Tags: html

Существует ли какой нибудь отладчик хтмл кода? Вопрос, конечно, смешной...но все же....!

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Используйте при написании кода нормальную IDE и возможно не придется пользоваться ссылкой выше.

Answer (score 1):

`Firebug` - попробуйте этим.

[Отладка кода с помощью Firebug](http://htmlbook.ru/samlayout/testirovanie-i-otladka-koda/firebug)